# css высота li элементов

Tags: html, css

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    font-family: TruenoRegular;
    background: #FFF;
    color: #fff;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
}

header {
    width: 100%;

}

nav {
    background: #472424;
}

.con {
    
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid red;
   
}

.menu {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;

    padding: 20px 0;
}

.menu a {
    color: #fff;
    
}

.menu ul {
    
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
li{

    outline: 1px solid red;

}

.left {
    width: 30%;
   
}
li:hover{
background-color:plum
}
```

```html
   <header>
        <nav>
            <div class="con">
                <div class="menu">
                    <div class="left">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Delivery</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Legal</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="right"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
```

Можно ли растянуть все li на всю высоту .menu чтобы при наведении область применения свойства background-color была как на nav'е stackoverflow? Важно сохранять размеры отступов `padding: 20px 0;` у блока с меню. Возможно ли это сделать не преминяя padding к самим li?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Когда код вставляете, там есть волшебная кнопочка - "Привести код в порядок"

Правильно задавать padding ссылкам и hover тоже

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: TruenoRegular;
  background: #FFF;
  color: #fff;
}

a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 10px 12px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
}

nav {
  background: #472424;
}

.con {
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.menu a {
  color: #fff;
}

.menu ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

li {
  outline: 1px solid red;
}

.left {
  width: 30%;
}

a:hover {
  background-color: plum;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <div class="con">
      <div class="menu">
        <div class="left">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Delivery</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Legal</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="right"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Ааа, эмммм, а как-же _Важно сохранять размеры отступов padding: 20px 0; у блока с меню._ ?   Резко неважно стало ?  P.S. Это вопрос автору, который отметил решение как верное, несмотря на вышеуказанное.

Comment: Не обижайся Хики

Comment: Было бы на что. Странно просто.